# Check if a Method has been Called

Tags: objective-c, ios7, methods

Is there any method, class or anything within Objective C, which detects or can detect if a Method has been called? so, I can write it in my if statement.

Comment: In what context? You can put a breakpoint in the method in the debugger. You can add a logging statement such as a call to `NSLog()` or `printf` or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

If you own the implementation of the method, you can use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to post a notification when you enter and exit the method. I did [something like this](http://www.sullinger.us/blog/2013/11/24/az766s0yc1zxrps2hf6em8nnv032ek) awhile back but for property changes. You could implement essentially the same thing.

#### Header

Create our API that just exposes the dedicated initializer, we provide the object we are monitoring and a method we want to invoke when the object has property changes. This could be re-wrote to use a codeblock if you wanted. I wrote this before I got heavy in to code blocks.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ObjectMonitor : NSObject

- (id)initWithMonitoringObject:(NSObject *)objectToMonitor respondingWithSelector:(SEL)selector;

@end
```

#### Implementation

Now you just implement the dedicated initializer, which breaks down the objects properties into a collection and registers itself as a KVO observer. The `observeValueForKeyPath` method then gets fired any time any of the properties within `objectToMonitor` change.

```
#import "ObjectMonitor.h"
#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>

@interface ObjectMonitor ()
@property (nonatomic) SEL selector;
@end

@implementation ObjectMonitor

- (id)initWithMonitoringObject:(NSObject *)objectToMonitor respondingWithSelector:(SEL)selector {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.selector = selector;

        unsigned int count;
        objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([objectToMonitor class], &count);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
            [objectToMonitor addObserver:self forKeyPath:key
                  options:0 context:NULL];
        }

        free(properties);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"%@ had %@ changed!", NSStringFromClass([object class]), keyPath);

    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[[object class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:self.selector]];
    if (invocation) {
        invocation.target = object;
        invocation.selector = self.selector;
        @try {
            [invocation invoke];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to invoke the method");
        }
        @finally {

        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Failed to locate the method for @selector:%@", NSStringFromSelector(self.selector));
    }
}
@end
```

#### Example usage

Instance the ObjectMonitor, associate a method callback to it and you are good to go. The `savePlayerSettings` method will be called anytime any property is changed within `MYPlayerSettings`

```
#import "MYPlayerSettings.h"
#import "ObjectMonitor.h"

@interface MYPlayerSettings ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) ObjectMonitor *objectMonitor;
@end

@implementation MYPlayerSettings

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.objectMonitor = [[ObjectMonitor alloc]
                              initWithMonitoringObject:self
                              respondingWithSelector:@selector(playerSettingsChanged)];
    }
    return self;

- (void)playerSettingsChanged {
    NSLog(@"%@ had settings changed", self.name);
}
```

I know you want to be notified of method invocations, but you can modify this a little bit by passing in the method you want to call, and  then changing a dedicated NSString property each time a method is fired to the name of the method. Then in your callback handler, you check what method was fired based on the changed value, and react accordingly.

Hope this helps.